# Group by month, sum one column and average another

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by, aggregate

I have the a dataframe that looks like the following:

| Date | Games Played | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-05-23 | 8 | 22 |
| 2023-01-29 | 10 | 32 |

The actual table is much longer. I want to group the table by month (the date column is a DateTime format column), and in doing so, sum together the games played column but average the rating column. Essentially, every row will have a month, total games played that month, and average rating for that month. How can I do these separate aggregations while still grouping by month in the date column.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
x = df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.month).agg({'Games Played': 'sum', 'Rating': 'mean'})
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
      Games Played  Rating
Date                      
1               13    18.5
5               11    21.0
```

---

DataFrame used:

```
        Date  Games Played  Rating
0 2019-05-23             8      22
1 2019-05-24             1      21
2 2019-05-25             2      20
3 2023-01-28             3       5
4 2023-01-29            10      32
```

---

If you want to group by *year* and *month*:

```py
x = df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.year, df['Date'].dt.month]).agg({'Games Played': 'sum', 'Rating': 'mean'})
print(x)
```

Comment: I'd use a monthly period (`df['Date'].dt.to_period('M')`) for the second one ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [aggregate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html)

```
df.groupby(df.Date.dt.month).aggregate(
    {'Games Played': 'sum', 'Rating': 'mean'})
```